# Excel Functions. If Conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

So that's the image link.
My problem is with the first part of the scenario where I am supposed to state the extras a person has bought and then decide the final pricing and automatically add it to the base headphone price.

```
Headphone = $70
Microphone = $30
Cat Speakers = $60 
Bluetooth = $50
Custom Des = $30
```

I would like to know the formula that needs to be used to add the amounts according to the extras along with the base price of the headphones.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual text instead of screenshots / photos / images. Others can't see clearly or copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

There's many ways to accomplish this but the easiest way is to have 3 columns that deal with the total.

One counts how many of each thing is being purchased (ex. if a headphone with cat ears is purchased, 1 will be in the column for each).

Second column lists the price for each corresponding item.

Third column multiplies the first and second column.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgJOD.jpg)

[image]

Comment: I suggest you to improve your answer by [edit]ing your post and showing the actual code / formula / data as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314547/how-do-i-paste-an-excel-sheet-to-the-questions-on-stack-overflow